# How to improve the algorithm to get a week days in a month Java 8 or 11

Tags: java, data-structures, stream

I am wondering how could I improve this pretty straightforward code.

The code is extremely verbose and two forLoops is something definitely not functional or concise.

I was thinking to use `Stream.iterate().limit(LAST_DAY_MONTH)` but it doesn't solve when we need to return a value.

```
public class WeekDaysPerMonth {

    public Map getNumberWeekDaysPerMonth(int year) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> weekDays = new Hashtable<>();
        for (int monthCount = 1; monthCount <= 12; monthCount++) {
            int daysCount = 0;
            final int LAST_DAY_MONTH = getLastDayMonth(monthCount, year);
            for (int day = 1; day <= LAST_DAY_MONTH; day++) {
                final int weekDay = LocalDate.of(year, monthCount, day).getDayOfWeek().getValue();
                daysCount = daysCount + (
                            (weekDay != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue()
                                && weekDay != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue())
                        ? 1 : 0);
            }
            weekDays.put(monthCount, daysCount);
        }
        return weekDays;
    }

    private int getLastDayMonth(int month, int year) {
        final boolean yearBiSexto = (year % 4 ) == 0;
        Map<Integer, Integer> lastDayMontMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
           put(1, 31);
           put(2, yearBiSexto ? 29 : 28);
           put(3, 31);
           put(4, 30);
           put(5, 31);
           put(6, 30);
           put(7, 31);
           put(8, 31);
           put(9, 30);
           put(10, 31);
           put(11, 30);
           put(12, 31);
        }};

        return lastDayMontMap.get(month);
    }
```

This is the result when we are providing the year 2022.

```
mes : 1 - mes : 21
mes : 2 - mes : 20
mes : 3 - mes : 23
mes : 4 - mes : 21
mes : 5 - mes : 22
mes : 6 - mes : 22
mes : 7 - mes : 21
mes : 8 - mes : 23
mes : 9 - mes : 22
mes : 10 - mes : 21
mes : 11 - mes : 22
mes : 12 - mes : 22
```

Please, any improvement would be great!

Comment: The first four weeks of the month will always contain 20 weekdays.  You only need to check what day of the week the 29th, 30th and 31st of the month are, if those days exist.

Comment: Hi @DawoodibnKareem - So lets say wk1 starts on Thurs (2d), wk2 (5d), wk3 (5d), wk4 (5d) - looks like 17d to me, not 20d !!

Comment: It is *either* 'pretty straightforward' *or* 'extremely verbose'. Not both at the same time. NB The word is 'algorithm', not 'algo'. It is derived from somebody's name. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: @MrR "week" meaning "7 days", obviously.  That's why it's only necessary to look at days 29, 30, 31 of the month.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - the OP code sample doesn't count Sat/Sun - so it's non-weekend days..

Comment: Thank you for all suggestions and corrections for this effortless algorithm. The target is count only the workdays.

Comment: @MrR - Yes, exactly.  That's why it's 20 days, not 28 in the first four weeks.  5 x 4 is 20.  Why is this hard for you to understand?

Comment: hey @DawoodibnKareem 
I don't consider it hard to understand. LocalDate, LocalDateTime and many other very common API are easy to me but lack of knowledge about the java.time.Month. This was crucial for functional style.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation based [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) Java 8.

- do not contain hardcoded values
- stream style

```java
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Map<String, Long> map = getNumberWeekDaysPerMonth(2022);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
        }

    }

    public static Map<String, Long> getNumberWeekDaysPerMonth(int year) {
        Map<String, Long> weekDays = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        EnumSet<DayOfWeek> weekends = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );

        Stream.of(Month.values()).forEach(month -> {
                    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(year, month);
                    long countWeekDays = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, yearMonth.lengthOfMonth()).filter(day ->
                            !weekends.contains(yearMonth.atDay(day).getDayOfWeek())
                    ).count();
                    weekDays.put(month.toString(), countWeekDays);
                }
        );

        return weekDays;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JANUARY:21
FEBRUARY:20
MARCH:23
APRIL:21
MAY:22
JUNE:22
JULY:21
AUGUST:23
SEPTEMBER:22
OCTOBER:21
NOVEMBER:22
DECEMBER:22
```

[YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) - is an immutable date-time object that represents the combination of a year and month

[Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) - is an enum representing the 12 months of the year

[LocalDate.getDayOfWeek()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek--) - gets the day-of-week of the date.

**EDIT:** Gathered to one stream, but the previous variant is more clear for understanding

```java
    public static Map<String, Long> getNumberWeekDaysPerMonth(int year) {
        EnumSet<DayOfWeek> weekends = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );
        return Stream.of(Month.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Enum::toString,
                month ->  IntStream.rangeClosed(1, YearMonth.of(year, month).lengthOfMonth()).
                          filter(day -> !weekends.contains(LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek())).
                          count(),
                (e1, e2) -> e1,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
```